# How to add external EJB to an Arquillian JUnit project?

Tags: java, maven, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have a Data project and an EJB project created. Now I have created another Arquillian project for testing the above two with it using JUnit. I have created pom.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.arquillian.unit.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>arquillian-test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-deprecated</id>
      <name>JBoss Deprecated</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-maven2-brew</id>
      <name>JBoss Maven 2 Brew Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2-brew/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>FocalColectEJB/com/focalinfo/service</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jbossas-managed-5.1</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-jbossas-managed-5.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-server-manager</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.3.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-client</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.0.GA</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

How to map my ejbs in order to be able to test them in my Arquillian project?

Comment: Can't you add your EJB module as a dependency to your Aruillian project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. If your EJB and other JAR are deployed separately to your app, you can use multiple deployments in your test case.  Only one is "testable" but both can be deployed.  You can simplify the reading of this external JAR file using ShrinkWrap's maven resolver.
2. If they are wrapped in to a WAR or EAR, just use that WAR or EAR as your deployment.